# MySQL LIMT is a subquery?

Tags: mysql, select, subquery, limit

I want to use a select statement to control the limit of another select query, I cant get it to work, what I have below. The Select in the braces returns an INT.
Im newer to MySQL so im not sure what I should use instead to get this to work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_prod` 
WHERE prod_id = 32 
ORDER BY prod_level ASC , prod_date 
LIMIT 
    (SELECT max_count 
    FROM Prod_subscription 
    WHERE prod_id = 32)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't write subquery in `LIMIT`, but you can use dynamic SQL to make your expected result.

```
SET @num = (
    SELECT max_count 
    FROM Prod_subscription 
    WHERE prod_id = 32);

PREPARE STMT FROM 'SELECT * 
FROM `tbl_prod` 
WHERE prod_id = 32 
ORDER BY prod_level ASC , prod_date 
LIMIT ?';
EXECUTE STMT USING @num;
```

Comment: I edited "can" to "can't" in the first sentence, because given the context I think that is what you meant. I make that mistake too!

Comment: @BillKarwin Oh, I didn't notice the mistake,thanks bro

Comment: will this work coming out of PHP ? I will give it a try.
BTW PHP Version is 7.4.28